# LINQ + CSV: How do i split a CSV file by its headers in C#

Tags: c#, linq, csv

this is my first post in here. I already tried to google and watch in stackoverflow but I didn't find a solution fitting to my problem, so I hope someone can help me here.

So I have a CSV-File with 3 columns:
ID, Name, PreferredFood

And I basically want to be able to split that CSV file into multiple CSV files, one file for each type of food.
So one file would have all IDs and names of the people who like pizza for example.

I am not even sure on how to work with a CSV here, I started off using a string[][] but I don't think that's the best way to do it. But that's another story...
For now I would be very grateful if anyone could help me with LINQ and how the statement would have to look like.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day :)
csharpdev

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

```
//class for the data:
class MyClass
{
    public string ID;
    public string Name;
    public string PreferredFood;
};

//mock data csv:
string csv = "A\tB\tc\nX\tY\tZ\n";

static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    //Spilt csv by End-of-Line separator:
    var lines   = csv.Split('\n');
    var mylist = new List<MyClass>();

    foreach( var line in lines )
    {
        //Spilt line by column separator:
        var columns = line.Split('\t');

        //create a new MyClass-object and insert the data into it 
        var s= new MyClass();
        s.ID            = columns[0];
        s.Name          = columns[1];
        s.PreferredFood = columns[2];

        //add the object into a list:
        mylist.Add( s );
    }

    //group the data using LinQ:
    var groups = mylist.GroupBy( x => x.PreferredFood );
}
```

Comment: Being a CSV file I would assume the use of commas, not tabs.

Comment: Also you should use `Environment.NewLine` and not `\n` as they are not the same on Windows.

Comment: you can also use commas. if you copy paste from excel, the generated csv-data is tab-separated.

Comment: It would then be a TSV file. CSV is specifically "Comma Separated Values".

Comment: I see a lot of csvs in my job, and all of them are separated either by commas or semicolons... ;-)
one way to look at it is that it is more likely to have a comma in a string than a tab. so to avoid escape-characters, you use the tab - which is also more readable in general.

Comment: thats a code *fragment*. feel free to add using , namespace and surraounding class definitions as you like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210341/discussion-between-draz-and-enigmativity).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
var csv = @"A,B,C
X,Y,Z
Q,W,E
R,S,Z";

var lines = csv.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

var results =
    from line in lines.Skip(1)
    let parts = line.Split(',')
    group line by parts[2] into foods
    select new
    {
        food = foods.Key,
        csv =
            String.Join(
                Environment.NewLine,
                new [] { lines[0] }.Concat(foods))
    };
```

That gives me:

[image: results]

You could then write out each CSV like this:

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    File.WriteAllText($"{result.food}.csv", result.csv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: CSV File]

With a csv file like above, you can create csv files for each preferred food like below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static string path = @"path\to\csv_file.csv";

        public class Person
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string PreferredFood { get; set; }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                // Matches what a csv line looks like
                return $"{Id},{Name},{PreferredFood}";
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path); // Read all lines of a csv file
            var groups = lines
                .Skip(1) // Skip header line
                .Select(line => line.Split(',')) // Split by comma
                .Select(column => new Person
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(column[0]),
                    Name = column[1],
                    PreferredFood = column[2]
                })// Convert to Person
                .GroupBy(person => person.PreferredFood); // Group by preferred food 

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                var foodPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), $"{group.Key}.csv"); // Create unique filename for each csv
                var foodOutput = new string[] { lines[0] } // Add header line
                    .Concat(group.ToList().Select(person => person.ToString())); // Concatenate all other lines
                File.WriteAllLines(foodPath, foodOutput); // Write output to csv foodPath
            }               

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```